# Cannot connect to the server deployed on kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have all ready prepared my docker image. 
My Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# Creating Application Source Code Directory
RUN mkdir -p /FogAPP/src

# Setting Home Directory for containers
WORKDIR /FogAPP/src

# Copying src code to Container
COPY fogserver.py /FogAPP/src

# Application Environment variables
ENV APP_ENV development

# Exposing Ports
EXPOSE 31700

# Setting Persistent data
VOLUME ["/app-data"]

#Running Python Application
CMD ["python", "fogserver.py"]
```

My source code fogserver.py (socket programming) :

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
import os

def ReceiveDATA():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    i=0
    host = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    port = 31700
    while True:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Create a socket object

        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port

        s.listen(10)                    # Accepts up to 10 clientections.


        print("############################# ",i+1," #################################")

        print('Server listening.... on '+ str(host))

        client, address = s.accept()

        print('Connection from : ',address[0])

        i+=1

        date=str(datetime.now())
        date=date.replace('-', '.')
        date=date.replace(' ', '-')
        date=date.replace(':', '.')

        PATH = 'ClientDATA-'+date+'.csv'

        print(date+" : File created")

        f = open(PATH,'wb') #open in binary

        # receive data and write it to file
        l = client.recv(1024)

        while (l):
            f.write(l)
            l = client.recv(1024)

        f.close()


        dt=str(datetime.now())
        dt=dt.replace('-', '.')
        dt=dt.replace(' ', '-')
        dt=dt.replace(':', '.')

        print(dt+' : '+'Successfully get the Data')

        feedback = dt

        client.send(feedback.encode('utf-8'))

        client.close()

        s.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReceiveDATA()
```

My kubernetes cluster is ready :

```
kubectl get nodes

NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
rpimanager   Ready    master   3d23h   v1.15.0
rpiworker1   Ready    worker   3d23h   v1.15.0
rpiworker2   Ready    worker   3d23h   v1.15.0
```

Then I have deployed the docker image in 2 pods through the kubernetes dashboard :

```
kubectl get services

NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
cluster-fogapp   NodePort    10.101.194.192   <none>        80:31700/TCP   52m
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP      3d23h
```

So actually docker image is runing in two pods :

```
kubectl get pods

NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cluster-fogapp-c987dfffd-6zc2x   1/1     Running   0          56m
cluster-fogapp-c987dfffd-gq5k4   1/1     Running   0          56m
```

and I have also a client source code which is also socket programming. Here I have found a problem which address of the server in cluster I have to put ?

This is my client code source :

```
    host = "????????????"#Which Address should I set  
    port = 31700

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))

    PATH = GenerateDATA()

    f = open (PATH, "rb")

    l = f.read(1024)

    while (l):
        s.send(l)
        l = f.read(1024)


    print(dt+' : '+'Done sending')
```

I have tried the address of the master node and I get an error of Connection refused.

I would like just to clarify that I am working on a cluster composed of raspberry Pi3 and the client is on my own pc. The pc and the raspberry cards are connected to the same local network.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Hi, are you accessing it from outside? if than `NodeIP:nodePort` which is for you `IP:31700`

Comment: The client is in my own pc which is connected WiFi also to the same network of the 3 raspberry cards.

Comment: what's the connection ?  `curl -v IP:31700` how are you connecting ?

Comment: Does your server work in a plain Docker environment, no Kubernetes?  (Usually you need to bind to 0.0.0.0 in a container environment, otherwise the container is unreachable from outside; there is no guarantee that the container's host name will resolve.)

Comment: @DavidMaze so I have to change the host address in server code to 0.0.0.0

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I didnt understand what do you mean ?

Comment: It would be good if you can show us the kubectl expose command used. Is the target-port correct?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I have succeeded to expose the app in cluster to outside through the ManagerIP:31700, But it doesnt support simultaneous connections. Is that should be configured from kubernetes or I have to change my server code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the service with the worker nodes IP since you exposed the service as NodePort.

`WorkerNode:<NodePort>`

The problem with this approach is that if any of the nodes are dead, you might face issue. The ideal solution is to expose the service as LoadBalancer, so that you can access the service outside the cluster with external IP or DNS.

Comment: ```
kubectl get services

NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
cluster-fogapp   LoadBalancer   10.103.239.184   <pending>     6443:32626/TCP   3m15s
```

It takes too much time the load balancing ?

Comment: Since you installed kubernetes on bare metal and not on cloud providers managed kubernetes setup, you will need additional setup to get load balancer. This might help.

Comment: https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-faq-how-can-i-route-traffic-for-kubernetes-on-bare-metal

Comment: If you are okay with the nodePort option that will work

Comment: I have added my client code on top, the problem is which IP address should I request ?

Comment: If you use NodePort access using either of the worker nodes ip  with NodePort as port

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to expose the app in cluster to outside through the node port mode : ManagerIP:31700. 
I would like to know where the cluster of raspberry stores the files of data that it have already received ?